# Один из потоков простаивает

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть такой класс Store, который представляет из себя "хранилище элементов" и 2 потока. Один бесконечно добавляет элемент(**ProducerThread**) в очередь, а второй бесконечно забирает(**ConsumerThread**) из очереди. Тот, который добавляет, отрабатывает нормально, а тот, который забирает - простаивает. Я запустил **debug** и посмотрел работу **ConsumerThread** , но только через **debug** он работает как надо. Почему в debug он работает нормально и где я ошибся ?

```
public class Store {
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static Deque<Integer> listOfNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
    private final static int STORAGE_CAPACITY = 10;

     public synchronized void produce() {
        while (listOfNumbers.size() == STORAGE_CAPACITY) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        int element = random.nextInt(50);
        listOfNumbers.add(element);
        System.out.println("Added element: " + element + "\nStorage size: " + getStorageSize() + "\n" + getListOfNumbers());
        notify();
    }

     public synchronized void consume() {
        while (listOfNumbers.size() == 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        int element = listOfNumbers.removeFirst();
        System.out.println("Received element: " + element + "\nStorage size: " + getStorageSize() + "\n" + getListOfNumbers());
        notify();
    }

    public int getStorageSize() {
        return listOfNumbers.size();
    }

    public Deque<Integer> getListOfNumbers() {
        return listOfNumbers;
    }
}
```

```
public class ProducerThread implements Runnable {
    Store store = new Store();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            store.produce();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ConsumeThread implements Runnable {
    private Store store = new Store();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            store.consume();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class NumberStorageDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread producer = new Thread(new ProducerThread(), "Producer");
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new ConsumeThread(), "Consumer");
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что каждый класс создает свой экземпляр `Store`, со своим списком для хранения объектов.

Писатель пишет в свой список, но читатель пробует доставать из совершенно другого (всегда пустого списка).

Исправить можно создав только одно хранилище:

```
public class ProducerThread implements Runnable {
  final private Store store;

  public ProducerThread(Store store) {
    this.store = store;
  }

  ...

}

public class ConsumerThread implements Runnable {
  final private Store store;

  public ConsumerThread(Store store) {
    this.store = store;
  }

  ...

}

Store sharedStore = new Store();
Thread producer = new Thread(new ProducerThread(sharedStore), "Producer");
Thread consumer = new Thread(new ConsumeThread(sharedStore), "Consumer");
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Проблема решена и все работает отлично